# Capturing audio stream in amr-nb format Winstore app

Tags: windows-runtime

I am looking for a solution to capture audio stream in amr-nb format in a WinStore app.

Is it possible to directly capture audio as amr-nb stream ?
or need to capture in pcm format and then transcode it to amr-nb stream?

thank in advance for providing an usage sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this codec but according to the [supported codec list from MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx) there is no builtin support for this codec with windows 8.0.

It appears that [windows 8.1 introduces amr-nb & amr-wb subtypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I think the transform is not builtin. Then you'll have to build a MediaExtension and ship it with your application. There are sample MFT on [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096).

There is another solution, maybe easier, not involving Media foundation. It consists on using WASAPI to gather raw audio data and encode it using a AMR library (you might need to do little adjustment to the AMR library to pass the WACK)